# Como desabilitar o auto search do JqueryDatatables?

Tags: jquery, jquery-datatables

Estou usando Jquery Datatables, e preciso remover o auto search que ele tem, deixando um botão "Buscar" ao lado

Alguém já fez isso?

Comment: Não foi bem desabilitar, mas como me incomodava o numero de requisições que ele gerava a cada keyup, então adicionei um timeout, se te servir eu posto como resposta.

Comment: Jader, minha ideia foi o seguinte, remover o Search atual, adicionar um novo input com botão "Buscar" e setar o filter no onClick desse botão

Comment: Procura a função: `function _fnFeatureHtmlFilter ( oSettings )` esta tudo ali... (na versão completa, pois na minificada muda os nomes das funções)

Comment: @Jader tem como colocar como colocou esse timeout na busco do datatable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A remoção dos search e outros inputs do Jquery DataTables é feita através do atributo dom

Resolvi meu problema utilizando isso:

```
 "dom": '<"top">rt<"bottom"ip><"clear">'
```

Ele remove apenas o Input e não a funcionalidade do search

Para mais detalhes, segue a [Documentação](http://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/dom.html)

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o [bFilter](http://legacy.datatables.net/ref#bFilter):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').dataTable({ "bFilter": false});
    });
```

Outra maneira de fazer isso é usando o'sDom':'t'. Onde parâmetro 't' significa "the table", ele remove header, footer, field search, pagination e outros componentes. Deixando somente a tabela.

Dá uma olhada nesse exemplo.

html:

```
<html>
    <title>exemplo</title>
        <head>          
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css">                
        </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="dataTable" id="example">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th>Rendering engine</th>
                <th>Browser</th>
                <th>Platform(s)</th>
                <th>Engine version</th>
                <th>CSS grade</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Presto</td>
                    <td>Opera 9.0</td>
                    <td>Win 95+ / OSX.3+</td><td>-</td>
                    <td>A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Presto</td>
                    <td>Opera 9.0</td>
                    <td>Win 95+ / OSX.3+</td><td>-</td>
                    <td>A</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable({"sDom":"t"});
});
```

Exemplo no jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ewertonorg/t4meLqrp/3/

Você pode ver uma lista de parâmetros no link: http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/options#sDom

Comment: Olá. Vi que sua resposta está correta. Mas seria bacana também você colocar na resposta o que significa esse parâmetro na construção da tabela (e até uma referência para a documentação dele). A resposta fica mais completa e facilita em ajudar usuários menos experientes (e a você ganhar mais votos positivos!). :)

Comment: Obrigado pela dica Luiz Vieira. Fiz uma pequena alteração na resposta e espero que tenha ficado mais fácil de entender.

Answer (score -1):

`$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#example1').DataTable({
          "filter": false
     });
});`